# issue importing a Site Collection using STSADM and 2010

Tags: publishing-site, import

So before anyone asks I need to use stsadm due to my lack of exposure to powershell.  Anyway,  I have run into issues using the export/import commands.  The source and target are 2010 publishing portals.  The goal is to quickly deploy a small root collection to a root at the target.   In the future it will be all managed by content deployment.

The site exported but on import errors occur.  Here is the detail.  As I indicated the publishing site has custom page layouts/masterpage and styles.  No custom features or web parts.

Verbose: Source URL: _catalogs/users
[12/16/2010 11:40:52 AM] [Folder] [users]   Error: 0x80070005Access denied.
[12/16/2010 11:40:52 AM] [Folder] [users]   Debug:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.UpdateFileOrFolderProperties(String bstrWebUrl, String bstrWebRelativeUrl, Object varProperties, Int32 fMigrationSemantics, Int32 fReGhost, Byte& piLevel)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFolder.UpdateOnImport()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.FolderSerializer.SetObjectData(Object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context, ISurrogateSelector selector)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.CallSetObjectData(Object obj, SerializationInfo objectData, ISerializationSurrogate surrogate, ISurrogateSelector selector)
[12/16/2010 11:40:52 AM] FatalError: 0x80070005Access denied.
[12/16/2010 11:40:52 AM] Debug:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.UpdateFileOrFolderProperties(String bstrWebUrl, String bstrWebRelativeUrl, Object varProperties, Int32 fMigrationSemantics, Int32 fReGhost, Byte& piLevel)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFolder.UpdateOnImport()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.FolderSerializer.SetObjectData(Object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context, ISurrogateSelector selector)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.CallSetObjectData(Object obj, SerializationInfo objectData, ISerializationSurrogate surrogate, ISurrogateSelector selector)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.ParseObject(Type objectType, Boolean isChildObject)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.DeserializeObject(Type objectType, Boolean isChildObject, DeploymentObject envelope)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ObjectSerializer.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImport.DeserializeObjects()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImport.Run()

Answer (score 1):

What version are you running?   Could this be a bug fixed by the October 2010 Cumulative Updates?  [KB 2394323](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2394323) for SP Foundation and [KB 2394320](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2394320) for SP Server?

Comment: good point.  I will identify version and see if this could be the issue/